# Eclipse (STS) to Bitbucket Communication

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit, spring-tool-suite

I'm receiving the following error trying to git pull/push the code into a remote Bitbucket repository:

[image]

however the same operation works fine from the command line.

How could I debug the situation further / fix it?

Here are the relevant git configurations on the CLI:

[image]

as well as in STS (Eclipse):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's Eclipse info:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the pointers leading to a solution.

Comment: I would include the "egit" tag in there, since this seems to be closely related to the git tooling in Eclipse.